# DIV not growing in width with fixed height while having css3 columns expand to the right

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sdthelord/tnsLE/

```
<div id="out">
  <div id="in">
    <P>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </P>
  </div>
</div>

#in {
  -moz-column-width: 200px;
  column-width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#out {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I have a DIV with CSS3 columns and a fixed height on a horizontal layout page. This div is contained within another div element, which includes the header h1 as well.

The point is, that I don't want to initially specify the width of both divs, so the width is either 100% or auto, and a min-width style makes sure it does not shrink (not in the fiddle).

The problem is, giving the div's border, you will see that even if new columns are added and more space is needed for content, the div's wont grow in size/width. 
Is there a way to force the div with the columns to be as large as to enclose all columns?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnsLE/1/)

Add `height: 100%;` to your `#in{...}` CSS

**i.e.**

```
#in {
    -moz-column-width: 200px;
    column-width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your tipp expands the div vertically, i try to have it expand to the right! I quote my first sentence: "I have a DIV with CSS3 columns and a fixed height on a horizontal layout page." so the height should be treated as given. New columns appear on the right as expected, only the width should resize as well. Easy to see an overflow: hidden hides the new columns.